# Two adjacent lists in python

Tags: python, string, lambda

I found this code example, which I think is very well written, but I'm having trouble understanding why part of it works.

The code searches for the longest word in a string:

```
def LongestWord(str):
    ''.join(map(lambda x: [' ',x][x.isalnum()], str)).split()
```

I have no idea how `[' ',x][x.isalnum()]` works. Does this construction have a name?

Comment: It's another way of implementing the ternary `lambda x: x if x.isalnum() else ' '`

Comment: note: "The code searches for the longest word in a string" - well, I guess this is just part of the code, because what you posted doesn't return anything.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath given that the result isn't assigned, it doesn't really *do* anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'm not sure the python compiler is *actually* able to optimize it to a noop. It probably will still eat the CPU cycles (but I'm too lazy to test). Hence the phrasing.

Comment: I would not consider that code sample well written. It is a hideous construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

break it into 2 parts...

```
[' ', x]
```

builds a list of 2 elements.  re-write as:

```
lst = [' ', x]
lst[x.isalnum()]
```

Now we see that the second brackets are to *index* the list created by the first brackets.  Since `str.isalnum()` returns a boolean (`True` or `False`) and since booleans behave like integers in python (`True` -> `1`, `False` -> `0`), then the construction just picks one of the two elements in the list.

Note that these days (python2.5 and later), it is more idiomatic (and probably more efficient) to use a conditional expression:

```
lambda x: x if x.isalnum() else ' '
```

Comment: Or avoiding the lambda altogether: `''.join(x if x.isalnum() else ' ' for x in str).split()`. Or better yet `re.split("[^A-Za-z]+", str)` -- the actual intention of the function.

Comment: @Dunes -- Yep.  Definitely better to avoid `lambda` + `map`.  I didn't think about optimizing the whole expression -- Just about optimizing the piece that I was explaining.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding this code is to know that boolean values can be used to index lists.

```
['a','b'][True] # produces 'b'
['a','b'][False] # produces 'a'
```

so the code

```
[' ',x][x.isalnum()]
```

will produce x if x is alpha-numeric otherwise it will produce ' '

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of breaking a sentence string apart into a list with single words but replacing all non-alphanumeric characters with a space which gets deleted by being a delimiter. To understand it, you have to start inside the map command. The string (str) gets checked by the lambda function, whether it is alphanumeric and if it is, the character stays the same ('x'), but if it is not, it gets replace by ' ' (space). The brackets work like [false,true][condition]. The map function iterates through the string (str). Then the resulting list (with single characters) gets joined to the complete sentence as a string (with the "".join command) and split into words (with the split() command, having a white-space character as a delimiter).